# Images on redux store not showing on URL having userID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a challenge please. I am fetching images from redux store to my react component like this

```
<img src={profile.Image.avatar} alt="IMG" />
```

When the browser,s URL has no id, it displays properly on browser

```
localhost:3000/dashboard //without userID
```

But once I redirect to a private page having a user's id on the URL, it won't display

```
localhost:3000/private/546794546 //with userID
```

Please how do I resolve this so I can use it on the img "src"

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't display"?

Comment: Is your image in public folder?

Comment: I don't get to see the image on my browser once it has an ID on the URL

Comment: @Kaleem yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it and let me know:

```
 const image = window.location.origin + "/" +profile.Image.avatar;
 <img src={image} alt="IMG" />
```

Comment: I'll upvote this a million time if only I could. Thanks for coming to my rescue. This worked perfectly.